# php textarea save as shown in

Tags: textarea

textarea automaticlly makes a new line when the text reaches the end window.
save the text in *.txt me stored in a line.
How to save the text in the form that I see?
if in php?

```
enter code here
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//narredi file
$ourFileName = "baza/$file1.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
//konec naredi

//shrani besedilo
$area=$_REQUEST['area'];

        //$area12 = explode(" ", $area);
        //$area12 = str_replace('\n', '<br />', $area);
```

$text = trim($_POST['area']); // remove the last \n or whitespace character
$text = nl2br($text);

```
$loadcontent = "baza/$file1.txt";
$fd=fopen("$loadcontent", "w+") or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fd,$text);
fclose($fd);
$file_contents=file_get_contents("baza/$file1.txt");



<textarea name="area" id="Data" wrap="on" cols=100 rows=5 >
test
testttt
testt</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Objavi" />
```

I have defined textarea size (css), and when I write the text longer of visible window then it create a visible new line in fact one line. I want two line or more....

Comment: em what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I have defined textarea size (css), and when I write the text longer of visible window then it create a visible new line in fact one line. I want two line or more....

Answer (score 0):

***for me it is so good***

```
$vrst = explode("\n", $loadcontent1);
$vrst1 = count($vrst);                        
$a = 0;
StartOfLoop: 
$lines = array_slice(explode("\n", $loadcontent1), "$a", 1);
$stevil = strlen($loadcontent1); 
$stevilo = $stevil / 88;
$stringpred = implode("\n", $lines);
$trimmed1 = strlen($stringpred);
        $vrstic = $trimmed1/88+1;
if (88 > $trimmed1) goto pogojzavec;
 foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
$a=0;
do
  {
$lines[$key] = substr(trim($value), "$a", "88+$a");
$string = implode("\n", $lines);
$stringg11 = $string;
$stringg2 = "$stringg2\n$stringg11";
$a =$a +88;
  }
while ($a<=$trimmed1);
        }
goto preskok;
pogojzavec:
 foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
   $lines[$key] = substr(trim($value), 0, 88);
}
$string = implode("\n", $lines);
$stringg11 = $string;
$stringg2 = "$stringg2\n$stringg11";
preskok:
      $a = $a + 1;
  if($a < $vrst1)  goto StartOfLoop;
```